# new 8TB HDD shows as 1.28 TB

Tags: external-hdd

Ubuntu_20.04, kernel 5.4.0-52-generic.

I have a new Seagate 8TB HDD attached via USB3 cable to an external drive interface card (labelled "Raptor 3.5 Main Board V3R1 2011/07/19", includes 12V power pack).
The drive shows as 1.28 TB in gnome-disk utility on /dev/sdb1 mount at /media/dk/8TB.
The drive's Partition Table is GPT.
The drive is formatted as ext4 (or ext3 or NTFS).

hdparm shows:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb1

/dev/sdb1:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST8000DM004-2CX188                      
    Serial Number:      ZCT2W041
    Firmware Revision:  0001    
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x006d) 
    Supported: 10 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 10
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors: 15628053168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:     7630885 MBytes
    **device size with M = 1000*1000:     8001563 MBytes (8001 GB)**
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 3.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5425
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Recommended acoustic management value: 208, current value: 208
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
            Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            unknown 119[6]
       *    unknown 119[7]
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
            DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
            unknown 78[7]
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            unknown 206[7]
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
            unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
       *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    964min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 964min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000c500c6805821
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 000c50
    Unique ID   : 0c6805821
Checksum: correct
$
```

Note that the logical Sector Size is 512 bytes and the physical Sector Size is 4096 bytes, and
Device Size = Cylinders x Heads x Sectors/Track x bytes/Sector = 8,001,563 MBytes.
But all other applications (gnome-disk-utility, gparted, fdisk, File Manager, etc.) see only 1.28 TB.
An existing 2TB HDD is seen as 2 TB and works OK.
On my laptop running LXLE (based on 18.04) it is the same.
This seems to point towards an error in the kernel.
Too many diagnostics to give here. I will update this if needed.

Comment: A "disk" is usually divided into "partitions". `/dev/sdb1` is one such (the 1th partition of the `/dev/sdb` disk). `sudo lsblk` , `sudo parted -l` will tell you about  the disk. If the NTFS partition was from a Windows Fast Boot  system, it could look corrupted.

Comment: Some of the external caddies or USB converters for a drive, do not support large drives. Is it newer and did it say it supported large drives?